# How to use HTML formatting with telegra.ph API

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-telegram-bot

I am using the `telegra.ph` [api](https://github.com/python273/telegraph/blob/master/telegraph/api.py) to edit the page I have made. I want to format the text that I have on the page to align to the right of the page. Right now the content that I am sending through a Python request is:

```
from telegraph import Telegraph
tel = Telegraph(my_access_token)

content = [{"tag": "h4",
            "children": ["Hello, World!"]},
            "attrs": {"dir": "rtl"}
            }]

page = tel.edit_page(path='/url',
                     title='testing',
                     content=content,
                     )
```

However the request completely ignores the `"dir": "rtl"` attribute, since "dir" is not one of the attributes that [Telegraph](http://telegra.ph/api) accepts. How can one align the text to the right through `telegra.ph`?

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telegraph only support limited HTML tag at this time, and you can't align via official editor too.

Please checkout [available tag list](http://telegra.ph/api#NodeElement)

Comment: Other than tags and attributes are there any other ways like Markdown or using another API to edit the pages I have made?

Comment: @Lexasaurus According to API document, only limited HTML tag can use at this time :(

Comment: @Lexasaurus: You have selected @Sean’s answer as a solution but you haven’t upvoted it. I think that’s a mistake.

Comment: does it support subscript and superscript?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is looking for an answer still, I could shift the text right to left by changing the title to Arabic/Farsi letters. In case your Arabic/Farsi text is formatted left to right, you can use Arabic/Farsi letters in the page title to fix it.